# Docker NGINX - PHP-FPM Cross Container Permissions?

Tags: docker, file-permissions, docker-volume

I'm setting up a wordpress stack and having cross file permissions.

When using `docker-compose up` permissions seem not to be a problem but when using local docker swarm and using `docker stack deploy`, nginx gives me a `403` for file permission errors. When inspecting both the `nginx:alpine` container and the `wordpress:php7.1-fpm-alpine` container, i do indeed see that the containers each have different permission, on the nginx side it marks the files inside `var/www/html` as owned by user and group id `82` while on the php7.1 they are owned by `www-data`.

How can I make sure permission is correct across containers? The files are being bind mounted from the host.

```

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: private/nginx
    build: 
      context: ./stack/nginx
    volumes:
      - "wordpress:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 80:80
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: private/wordpress
    build: 
      context: ./stack/wordpress
    volumes:
      - "wordpress:/var/www/html"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - "mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  wordpress:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: "${PWD}/wordpress"
  mysql:
```

```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this question and has no solution,
this is how I approached the situation.

I added the following to my dockerfile, it creates a new `www-data`group AND user with the same `id` as the `id` that is used for the `www-data` user `82` & group `82` in the `php-fpm` image.

```
RUN set -x ; \
addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1
```

To my docker file for nginx.

and in my `nginx.conf` i set the nginx worker user to the newly created ww-data user.

```
user www-data;
```